# Glibc 2.7 configure error programs too old

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, glibc

When i load a GenomicFeatures package in R, it pop up a error message:

```
Loading required package: IRanges
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/caohf/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/IRanges/libs/IRanges.so':
  /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /home/caohf/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/IRanges/libs/IRanges.so)
Error: package ‘IRanges’ could not be loaded
```

so i want to install glibc2.7, the source was downloaded from this [site](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/).

I configure the soure as non-root:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/home/cao/bin
```

there is a configure error on the screen:

> checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   configure: running configure fragment for add-on nptl
>   checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/x86_64/elf nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64   sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64     nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux nptl/sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/common sysdeps/unix/mman sysdeps/unix/inet nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 nptl/sysdeps/unix sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/fpu nptl/sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic/elf sysdeps/generic
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking for gcc... gcc
>   checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
>   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
>   checking for g++... g++
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
>   checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
>   checking for ranlib... ranlib
>   checking whether /usr/libexec/binutils220/as is GNU as... yes
>   checking whether ld is GNU ld... yes
>   checking for /usr/libexec/binutils220/as... /usr/libexec/binutils220/as
>   checking version of /usr/libexec/binutils220/as... 2.20.51.0.2, bad
>   checking for ld... ld
>   checking version of ld... 2.17.50.0.6, ok
>   checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
>   checking for gcc... gcc
>   checking version of gcc... 4.4.6, ok
>   checking for gnumake... no
>   checking for gmake... gmake  checking version of gmake... 3.81, ok
>   checking for gnumsgfmt... no
>   checking for gmsgfmt... no
>   checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
>   checking version of msgfmt... 0.14.6, ok
>   checking for makeinfo... no
>   checking for sed... sed
>   checking version of sed... 4.1.5, ok
>   checking for autoconf... autoconf
>   checking whether autoconf works... yes
>   configure: error:
>   These critical programs are missing or too old: as
>   Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

Below is the recommended tools for compilation in the INSTALL file(and the version in my system):

1 GNU make 3.79 or newer
my system:

> GNU Make 3.81

2 GCC 3.4 or newer, GCC 4.1 recommended
my sys:

> gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC)

3 GNU binutils 2.15 or later
i don't know how to check the version of binutils,but

```
 as -v
 ld -v
```

> GNU assembler version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 20061020
>   GNU ld version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 20061020

4 GNU texinfo 3.12f
I don't the version either? need help

5 GNU awk 3.0, or higher
my sys:

> GNU Awk 3.1.5

6 Perl 5
mine:

> This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

7 GNU sed 3.02 or newer
mine:

> GNU sed version 4.1.5

8 GNU autoconf 2.53 or higher
mine:

> autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.59

9 GNU gettext 0.10.36 or later
mine:

> gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.14.6

I am in :

> CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
>   Linux iodell-01 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5

Do i have to install the newer version of glibc, I am afraid the system's package is too old for the newer one. 
how can i figure it out? thank you

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar problem. The issue is with regex for as,ld in configure.in file.

Knowing that I have 2.20 which is certainly >2.15 (as per INSTALL file), I update the regex from

```
[2.1[3-9]*]
```

I commented the Version check for as,ld. Technically I should fix that Regex but unfortunately something like this didnt work

```
[2.20*]
```

As I didnt want to waste much time, just commented it for now and removed the check from configure file. Will update the post later with proper regex.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a bunch of times on my system back when I was using Debian (stable branch), which is known to have outdated packages. As far as I know the only way is to upgrade glibc, which means upgrading the entire system. If you got a lot of time you can upgrade JUST glibc, but that is usually more trouble than it's worth since the newer version may have newer symbols and old symbols may have been relocated. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did the above, didn't solve the problem, then did the following and now works:

1. Edit the ./configure script itself (not ./configure.in -or- as-well-as the configure.in as mentioned above if you like), locate the following CASE lines (on my GLIBC2.7 the lines are located in 4530 and 4596):

case $ac_prog_version in

```
case $ac_prog_version in
'') ac_prog_version="v. ?.??, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
  2.1[3-9]*)
      ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
```

Add the following to them to allow your version:

```
2.2[0-9]*)
   ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
```

Do both the AS and LD check (line numbers mentioned above), I did that and mine worked.

Good luck, I hope this helps

H